# Boolean logic in where clause

Tags: mysql, boolean

I want to include a record so long as both value_1 and value_2 are not 0. Why does this query below exclude the record? How do I adjust this to say 'I want to include both values so long as both are not simultaneously 0'?

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM (
    SELECT
      0 as 'value_1',
      218 as 'value_2'
) a
WHERE  
  value_1 <> 0
  AND value_2 <> 0
```

Comment: AND should be OR

Comment: @Barmar wouldn't that mean either could be 0?

Comment: No. Because then both tests will be FALSE, and FALSE OR FALSE is FALSE.

Comment: Maybe it's more obvious if you write `WHERE NOT (value_1 == 0 AND value_2 == 0)`

Comment: Google "de Morgan's Laws"

Comment: @JosephErickson `<>` is `!=`.   The row isn't there because `value_1 != 0` is `FALSE` (since it _is_ `0)`, thus the whole thing is `FALSE`.  What you want is `NOT (value_1 = 0 AND value_2 = 0)`, which is "not 'both values are `0`'".  Using [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), that can convert to `value_1 != 1 OR value_2 != 0`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat very helpful. I'm a little baffled. Will look further into it.

Comment: @JosephErickson I agree, it can be a little confusing :)

Comment: can you add more sample data with the expected out to make your question more clear.

Comment: @JosephErickson `x AND y` is true if both `x` and `y` are true. In your example `value_1 <> 0` is false, so they're not both true.